# self signed certificate for telegram bot in php curl

Tags: php, curl, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I just wanna send a simple request to telegram bot APIs my code is:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.telegram.org/bot332537240:MY_TOKEN/getUpdates",
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

returns:

```
cURL Error #:SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
```

I don't want use any ssl. I wont set any webhook for telegram. this is a simple request and I failed to handle this. please help me

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21188224

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem and can be solved by copying file **cacert.pem** into my server and then insert the path of cacert file into my PHP script. In my case i put file cacert into drive C of my web server and then insert this script into my PHP File:

> CURLOPT_CAINFO => "C:\cacert.pem"

So your PHP script should be like this:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.telegram.org/bot332537240:MY_TOKEN/getUpdates",
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_CAINFO => "C:\cacert.pem",
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

You can download file **cacert.pem** from:

> https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FCLH88MpKNLDXZg3pJUSAZ0BbUbNmBR2

If you still confuse, you can view my complete tutorial video on my youtube:

> https://youtu.be/UNERvcCz-Hw

Answer (score 0):

telegram webhook only work with ssl. you can simply use cloudflare free ssl.
but it's not working for .ir domains.
you can get update much more easier.

```
<?php 

date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Berlin");
define('BOT_TOKEN', 'yourtoken');

define('API_URL', 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.BOT_TOKEN.'/');
//get update
$content = file_get_contents("php://input");

//json array
$update = json_decode($content, true);
//chatid
$chatID = $update["message"]["chat"]["id"];
?>
```

Comment: I don't use webhook. I need ssl for sending message too? or getMe method?

Comment: i think just webhook need ssl.i complete my answer with php code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` and set it to false in  `curl_setopt_array`.

`CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` stop cURL from verifying the peer's SSL certificate.

Hope it should help.

Comment: Could you give a small explanation about what `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` does and how it solves the problem? This would greatly improve the quality of the answer

Comment: Please add that explanation to your answer by editing it

Answer (score 0):

if you want playing with methods and get a overall understanding how telegram bot works,just put the url in browser and see the results.

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/METHOD_NAME
```

for your problem i think you are using really old curl library , get latest cacert file from [here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) and replace it with the old one. if you are using xampp follow [this](http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/196/xampp-wampp-php-ssl-certificate-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate) link for more info